# microsoft graph BETA add Microsoft Teams channel with isfavoritebydefault

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create channels in Microsoft Teams using the Microsoft Graph Beta API. In the docs, it says that the channel entity has a property `IsFavoriteByDefault` that indicates

> Whether the channel should automatically be marked 'favorite' for all
>   members of the team. Default: false.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-beta#properties

However, trying the Graph Beta API (either with custom call or the Graph Explorer) and whatever value I pass to this property `true` or `false`, this property remains `null`.

[image: exhibit from Graph Explorer]

Is there anything special to do to actually set the value of this property ?

Comment: No answer so far... hang on! https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4241
Hope MS will solve this bug soon.

Comment: I am calling beta graph api from the HTTP connector in a power automate flow to create team and channels and using `"isFavouriteByDefault": true` doesn't seem to unhide channels (in browser or native client), they are all hidden by default.

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone found a resolution to this? I added the isFavoritebyDefault but I am seeing this only adds this for the owner or user who runs the flow not for all members of the team. Code is provided below for reference.

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "url": "/teams/{varTeamID}/channels",
      "method": "POST",
      "id": 1,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": {
        "displayName": "{varChannelName}",
        "description": "This channel is in existence for",
        "isFavoriteByDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-beta) shows as ,

> Indicates whether the channel should automatically be marked
> 'favorite' for all members of the team. Can only be set
> programmatically with [Create team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-beta). Default: false.

That means setting `IsFavoriteByDefault` to true won't work on create channel api call.
But it will work as part of the create Team API where channel(s) can be added and set as IsFavoriteByDefault as true