# Hot to create new channel in Teams that is not hidden, using GraphAPI

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have an app that uses microsoft's graphAPI to create channels in my organizations Team dynamically. All is well and I can create the channels, except the channels I'm creating are marked as hidden - users need to manually "show" the channel before reading messages or even get notifications.

Is there any way to bypass this "hidden" thing? Can i force the created channels to be visible for every user in the team, without the approving them first.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this function is controlled by [isFavoriteByDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/channel?view=graph-rest-beta#properties), and when setting it to true, the channel should automatically be marked 'favorite' for all members of the team.

Unfortunately, after doing some research and test, I find that this property can't be changed through Graph API. So currently we can't bypass the "hidden" thing.

A similar post: [Microsoft graph BETA add Microsoft Teams channel with isfavoritebydefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136212/microsoft-graph-beta-add-microsoft-teams-channel-with-isfavoritebydefault). The Microsoft engineer mentioned that could be they didn't fix the path `POST /teams/id/channels`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add this but I see some inconsistency in the responses. For example if i run a flow that does the graph api process to create a channel within a team it only sets the show under channels for my account not the rest of the users associated with it. I don't know if anyone else has experienced this or has a fix.

Here is my sample:

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "url": "/teams/{varTeamID}/channels",
      "method": "POST",
      "id": 1,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": {
        "displayName": "{varChannelName}",
        "description": "This channel is in existence for",
        "isFavoriteByDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```